# Passagem de parâmetros via AJAX

Tags: java, ajax, java-ee, jsp

Estou desenvolvendo a parte de cadastro dos clientes na minha aplicação e está realizando o cadastro no banco de dados normalmente, mas gostaria de que quando eu fizer o cadastro e ser redirecionado para pagina `ConfirmacaoCadastro.jsp` ele pegasse o email que passei por parametro e colocar na pagina mais isso não esta acontecendo.

AJAX

```
 function cadastrar(){


           $.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "CadastroCliente",  
data: {
    nome: $("input[id=nome]").val(),
    cep: $("input[id=cep]").val(),
    celular: $("input[id=nr_celular]").val(),

    cpf: $("input[id=cpf]").val(),
    uf: $("input[id=uf]").val(),

    cidade: $("input[id=cidade]").val(),
    rua: $("input[id=rua]").val(),
    rg: $("input[id=rg]").val(),

    bairro: $("input[id=bairro]").val(),
    telefone: $("input[id=telefone]").val(),
    login: $("input[id=login]").val(),
   senha: $("input[id=senha]").val(),
    confirmar_senha: $("input[id=confirma_senha]").val(),
    data_nascimento: $("input[id=nascimento_dt]").val(),
     estado_civil: $("input[name='status']:checked").val(),
     sexo: $("input[name='sexo']:checked").val(),
     email: $("input[id=email]").val(),

},


success: function(result){   
 window.location.href = "ConfirmacaoCadastro.jsp?email="+email;

},
 error:function(){
     alert("erro");
        },
});

       }
```

ConfirmacaoCadastro.jsp

```
           <div class="row">

           <div class="col-sm-4">

                       <h3> Confirmação de Cadastro </h3>

                        </div>


                                </div>

                                <div class="row">


                                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                                        <h4> Seus dados foram enviados para o email <p>${param.email}</p> </h4>

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                         <div class="row">


                                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                                        <img src="imagens/voltaPagina.JPG" alt="voltarPaginaPrincipal" class="volta">

                                        <a href="index.jsp"> Voltar Pagina Principal</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Pagina sem o e-mail passado pelo parametro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está concatenando uma variável que não existe (email):

`window.location.href = "ConfirmacaoCadastro.jsp?email="+email;`

Declare a variável email com o valor do input de id email:

```
success: function(result){
    var email = $("input[id=email]").val();
    window.location.href = "ConfirmacaoCadastro.jsp?email="+email;
}
```

Comment: nossa era isso mesmo, desatenção minha,obrigado Samuel

Comment: não tem porque agradecer.. e imagino que está codificando a muitas horas seguidas, é normal dar algumas panes kkkk